# how to save additional columns in session store table using express-session

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express-session

In my NodeJS application I'm using express-session middleware to save user session data into PostgreSQL database. I noticed, express-session defaults to save only sid (string), sess (json), expire (datetime) in the database table specified for session storage.

But I have additional columns (userId, userType, etc) as well in the session table, Is there a way to save them along with the user session. Though we can save this additional data in sess column, I want to save in the specific columns for more flexibility.

Also, it's not allowing me to save session data if I changed the column names (changed 'sid' to 'user_session_id') of the Table.
Is that expected? Is there any way to change the column names.

Code snippet provided below for reference

```js
enum SessionConfig {
    name = 'xc2id',
    tableName = 'session',
    schemaName = 'xc2',
    sessionPruneInterval = 20 //seconds
}

export const pgPool = new pg.Pool({
    host: config.DB_HOST_NAME,
    port: parseInt(config.DB_PORT),
    database: config.DB_NAME,
    user: config.DB_ADMIN_USERNAME,
    password: config.DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD,
    ssl: true
});

//Todo: cookie - secure: true
const sessionCookie = {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: parseInt(config.COOKIE_MAX_AGE)
};

const sessionStore = new pgSession({
    pool: pgPool,
    tableName: SessionConfig.tableName,
    schemaName: SessionConfig.schemaName,
    pruneSessionInterval: SessionConfig.sessionPruneInterval
});

export const sessionMiddleWare = session(
    {
        name: SessionConfig.name as string,
        genid: () => BLHelper.getRandomSHA256(),
        store: sessionStore,
        secret: config.SESSION_SECRET_CODE,
        cookie: sessionCookie,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    }
);
```